# Laravel 5.8 Login customization for individual user session lifetime

Tags: laravel, authentication, customization

Following situation.
From Monday to Friday, between 8am and 7pm the session liftime for every user is rest minutes till 7pm. after 7pm session lifetime 15 Minutes. I find a solution to create a middleware and set config(['session.liftetime'].....) before the session is created. it works, but for every user.

After consulting the customer he want now the option in the login form, that the user can activate this function. so i need now customization the login and transfer the request infos of the form option to my middleware.

how can i solve this problem?

Thanks for every help